# SQL Job step history to display DML changes

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dml

A vendor provided a script to run with many DML statements and i dump this in a stored procedure to run it from SQL job. When running the script via SSMS, it returns affected row counts after going through each DML statements such as "update". How can i quickly get the row counts to appear in SQL job step or dump to a text file via job step without setting using @@rowcounts after each of the DML statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLCMD through a cmdexec jobstep, instead of TSQL step.